# 4 div's in one line, move div to new line

Tags: html, css

I have code like:

```
    <div style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; border-spacing: 10px;">

<div style="text-align: center; display: table-cell;">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>

<div style="text-align: center; display: table-cell;">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>

<div style="text-align: center; display: table-cell;">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>


<div style="text-align: center; display: table-cell;">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>

</div>
```

it work correctly from PC, but on mobile devices it's work very ugly, all images and text go floor. How it can be modified, that the div can format 4x1 line, 2x2 line centered, 1x4 line centered (for mobiles).

Comment: look into Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Bootstrap for something that could be solved with a couple of media queries, that's a bit overkill, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a responsive grid system. So you need to add some CSS that has a grid system and is also responsive. The most common one for years has been Bootstrap.

Just add the following CSS to your HTML in the head section:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Here is the website for Bootstrap if you want to learn more:
http://getbootstrap.com/

Next you want to use the grid system, Bootstrap uses a 12 unit grid system so the whole page is divided into 12 blocks. It also defines each device to one of the following based on its size: XS, SM, MD, LG

Learn more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

So long story short, a mobile is considered XS (Extra Small) Portrait and Lanscape can be different though, so your existing HTML should be as such:

```
 <div class="container" style="text-align:center">  <div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
<a href="#"><img src="/image.png" alt="" width="auto" border="0" /></a>
<br> 
Text 
</div>

</div></div>
```

Comment: How it can be centered, it look very good, if add center all div it will be best!

Comment: @user2421781 I am not sure what you're exactly trying to do but I edited the code so there is a container now that always centers, in addition if you want the text center you need to add the CSS code, I added an inline style to the container for example.